# URL to login with redirect URL after completion

Tags: login, redirect

I have used `->isLoggedIn()` method to detect whether a Magento user is logged in at that exact point.  Now, I need to direct them to login IF they are not logged in, and specify a redirect URL upon success (which is not the same as the current URL - instead it will need a few extra parameters).

How do I do this?  BTW we have Magento 1.4

I will be using:

```
Mage::getUrl(‘customer/account/login’);
```

to get the url, but it's how to redirect to a point that I don't know.

**EDIT**..
@Marius' post below was helpful and worked, but in some cases you may need to do a base64_encode yourself.  essentially, whatever your login url is, make sure you add a trailing slash /, then add referer/nnnnnn where nnn is the base64_encode'd URL.  To encode with JAVASCRIPT, I found this function, you can add it to your utilities:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript
to here:
http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode/

```
base64_encode: function(data) {
    //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode/
    // original by: Tyler Akins (http://rumkin.com)
    // improved by: Bayron Guevara
    // improved by: Thunder.m
    // improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // improved by: Rafał Kukawski (http://kukawski.pl)
    // bugfixed by: Pellentesque Malesuada
    // example 1: base64_encode('Kevin van Zonneveld');
    // returns 1: 'S2V2aW4gdmFuIFpvbm5ldmVsZA=='
    // example 2: base64_encode('a');
    // returns 2: 'YQ=='
    var b64 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
    var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
        ac = 0,
        enc = '',
        tmp_arr = [];
    if (!data) return data;
    do { // pack three octets into four hexets
        o1 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
        o2 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
        o3 = data.charCodeAt(i++);

        bits = o1 << 16 | o2 << 8 | o3;

        h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
        h2 = bits >> 12 & 0x3f;
        h3 = bits >> 6 & 0x3f;
        h4 = bits & 0x3f;

        // use hexets to index into b64, and append result to encoded string
        tmp_arr[ac++] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
    } while (i < data.length);
    enc = tmp_arr.join('');
    var r = data.length % 3;
    return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 3);
}
```

Comment: can you post some code, or at least the area where you are checking (model, controller, block) ?

Comment: I added the url-out code.  BTW here is the link I got that from.  It's the return I don't know how to do.

https://mayankpatel104.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/how-to-get-the-customer-login-logout-register-and-checkout-url/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to redirect after login to the url  `Mage::getUrl('something/goes/here')`.

Do this:

```
$redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl('something/goes/here');
$encodedUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($redirectUrl);
$loginUrl = Mage::getUrl(
     'customer/account/login', 
      array(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME => $encodedUrl)
);
```

Then redirect to `$loginUrl`.
Just make sure you have config setting `System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Login Options->Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in` set to `No`.